# VBA msgbox duplicate value base on 2 columns

Tags: vba, duplicates, msgbox

I'm trying to get a msgbox when a value is duplicate base on 2 columns. The first column Value can be repeated but the second column will determine if it's a duplicate or not.

i.e.

Column B = Code,
Column L = Month

The user can enter the Code several times, but if he enters it on the same month I want the msgbox pop up

Answer (score 0):

Is your intention to warn\inform the user? If so, I would do this without a macro. I would use conditional formatting to make the cell change color whenever the duplicate information is entered.

1. Create a column on your worksheet with a formula that concatenates the information in column B&L the formula would be `=B1&L1` (copy this formula down the table). You can hide the column so nobody sees it. For this example, let's say you used column "M".
2. Select the entire Code or Month column (or both) and click the CONDITIONAL FORMATTING button on the Home tab, choose NEW RULE, USE FORMULA TO DETERMINE WHICH CELLS TO FORMAT, then enter the following formula: `=COUNTIF($M$4:$M$1000,M1)>1`  (note I am assuming your range of data is less than 1000 records, otherwise increase that number). Set the format to something like a red fill and instantly duplicates will be flagged. The user will also be able to quickly locate the record where this combination was already entered as that will turn red too.

If you really do want a macro to do this, you could simply write a loop to compares the active cell value of B(activerow) & L(activerow) to each previous B#&L# combination. If a match is found, use the intersect method to pop-up a the message. Here is really a good article about the intersect method: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/vba-intersect.htm.